# Conversão de String para Double Asp.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Preciso converter um valor de String (retornado pelo banco de dados) para Double mas quando vou fazer isso, ele simplesmente modifica o valor. Exemplo: o banco retorna 22.5, quando converto para Double em 225.0.

```
String val_serv = consultaserv[2].ToString();
Double buffer = Convert.ToDouble(val_serv);
totalserv = buffer + totalserv;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a sobrecarga do método `Convert.ToDouble` que recebe um `IFormatProvider` como um parâmetro. Se for usado o `Convert.ToDouble` sem essa sobrecarga é utilizada a cultura na qual o programa esta rodando. Por isso que quando tu converte o valor 25.5 ele se transforma em 255, pois o "." é separador de centena, e não de decimal em algumas culturas (pt-BR sendo uma dessas).

```
Convert.ToDouble(val_serv, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

ou

```
Convert.ToDouble(val_serv, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"));
Convert.ToDouble(val_serv, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

Assim:

```
double.Parse(consultaserv[2].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Você poderia explicar isso? Porque o original `Convert.ToDouble` está errado? Assim, todos podemos entender o problema. =D

Comment: Não que esteja errado, mas que este `Convert.ToDouble()` não leva em consideração que a `string` possui um formato a ser lido. No caso do `Parse`, usa-se o `InvariantCulture`, que força o método a converter a `string` para o formato mais usado mundialmente.